# How to delete all resources related to a specified url in zapproxy scan?

Tags: java, zap, zapproxy

I'm using the java client api of [zapproxy](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy) to detect the vulnerability of many websites automatically and dynamically.I need to release all resources(alerts,spider result,active scan result,memory usage) for the specified url and not interfere scans of other urls.

overview the whole api of zapproxy,I only got :

```
http://localhost:8080/UI/core/action/deleteAllAlerts
```

which i think will delete all alerts including those belong to the other urls.

So,how to delete resources for a specified url in zapproxy scan?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, missed this one - I've been looking for the 'zap' tag ;)

You can use the API call:

```
http://localhost:8080/UI/core/action/deleteSiteNode
```

which will delete the relevant node in the Sites tree and associated alerts.

Dont think that will delete the subtree though - could you submit a feature request for this? https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/new

Thanks